# chroot() function returning "undefined function error" in php

Tags: php

I am trying to change the path of a file (saved in /foo/bar directory) to the root

forexample

```
www.example.com/foo/bar/user.php
```

to

```
www.example.com/user.php
```

using chroot() function

```
<?php
chroot("/foo/bar/user.php");
$n=getcwd();
echo $n;
```

it's not working, I am getting the following php error :

```
call to undefined function chroot()
```

I am using php 5.3*, But I have also tested it on 5.4+ , still the same error. I am not sure if it is because of the the versions or something else,

Please help!

Comment: After reading your question twice, I have no idea what you expect the `chroot` function to do. What you did try to do with it makes no sense. The argument has to be a directory, and you appear to be giving it a file name. And there is no `foo` in the root of any of the standards I have come across, so the given path wouldn't exist either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the following from the [docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chroot.php):

> This function is only available to GNU and BSD systems, and only when
>   using the CLI, CGI or Embed SAPI. Also, this function requires root
>   privileges.

Are you trying to use it on a Windows platform? If so this will not work.

Comment: Yes,I am on the windows platform, it means the function is not available for me, anyway, thanks for the useful information and link.