# Normalize/Standard path root to CLI/WEB

Tags: php, document-root

I have this short script to detect the user usage environment and try to normalize the root path:

Located in `C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\Last-Hammer\configs\const\loader.php`

```php
$env= '';
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    $env= 'cli';
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PWD'])) {
        $path = dirname(__DIR__).'\\';
    } else {
        $path = dirname($_SERVER['PWD']);
    }
} else {
    $env= 'web';
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
echo $path;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $env;
file_get_contents($path.'configs/const/client.xml')
```

i use it from 2 diferent files: `index.php` that wor well in root folder but trying to use it from a sub-directory like this `/dev/cron.php`

`cron.php` content:

```php
$path = (!isset($_SERVER["PWD"]) ? dirname(__DIR__).'\\' : dirname($_SERVER["PWD"]));
require_once $path.'/configs/const/loader.php';
```

i get this output

```
//from Web environment 
C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/t2/Last-Hammer/ 
web
```

and

```
//from CLI environment 
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\Last-Hammer 
cli
```

the problem is that this work correctly from Web environment but not work correctly in CLI, when i try to execute like: `php cron.php` code try to make a file_get_contents... like this using cli get this error:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\Last-Hammer\configs\configs/const/client.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\Last-Hammer\configs\const\loader.php on line 24

> Warning: file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\Last-Hammer\configs\configs/const/client.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\Last-Hammer\configs\const\loader.php on line 24

what is expected is that both for CLI or WEB, the root of the project is similar to: `C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/t2/Last-Hammer/` and does not change constantly in the case of CLI depending on where it is executed the php file, as root could set in CLI. regardless of where it runs.

Comment: You show a `require_once` error but no code and you don't show a `file_get_contents` error.

Comment: @AbraCadaver sorry my miss... i have update with the righ error output

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking trailing "\" on cli case. to uniform both, you could use str_replace():

```
$env= '';
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    $env= 'cli';
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PWD'])) {
        $path = dirname(__DIR__).'\\';
    } else {
        $path = dirname($_SERVER['PWD']).'\\';
    }
} else {
    $env= 'web';
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
$path = str_replace( '\\', '/', $path );
echo $path;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $env;
file_get_contents($path.'configs/const/client.xml')
```

Comment: whe i use `'\\'` get this path: `C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\Last-Hammer\configs\ ` that add `\configs\ ` this is a error getting: `'configs\configs/'`

Comment: I have verified and there is a collision in the string since `__DIR__` brings the current execution directory and not the root of the server.

Answer (score 0):

[define](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) in your main scripts:

```
define('DOCROOT', '../'); // this in your cron.php
define('DOCROOT', './'); // this in your index.php
```

Just use relative paths:

```
$path = DOCROOT;
file_get_contents($path.'configs/const/client.xml')
```

Comment: not work,  `configs/const/client.xml` not relative to the execution you have read the post???

Comment: _PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(./configs/const/client.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\Last-Hammer\configs\const\loader.php on line 30_

Comment: @walternunez Sure i have. Then add some `../../` or `./some/dir` so you point to the right place. I dont know your directories.

Comment: @walternunez you may want to set [`chroot`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chroot.php) before you use the relative path, so you start from the same position every time. Set it in your `index.php` and `config.php` or `cron.php` or whatever you main script is. You can set chroot relative from your main script too.

Comment: `chroot` need a string path like this: `("/path/to/your/chroot/");` i cant determinate this string when i am runing a script from sub-directory of root check the post `cron.php` is on `/dev/` sub-directory that work well and load the `loader.php` but `loader.php` break when try to get a file with `file_get_content()`

Comment: chroot takes relative paths too.

Comment: not work:  _PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function chroot() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\Last-Hammer\configs\const\loader.php:8_

Comment: Oh... [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542240/chroot-function-returning-undefined-function-error-in-php), nice - will fix my answer.